# How do I make a POST request from a third-party Web App in a secure way with PHP?

Tags: php, rest, security, oauth, http-post

I have a website where users have points to do various activities.
One of the ways to receive these points is from third-party Apps I'm allowing to send them.

I would like the points to be only assigned only when the user is logged in on both sites. So, the flow would look like this:

1. The user is on the third-party website and submits a form "Claim my points" (at this point the amount of points, User ID, and partner(from who) ID is sent);
2. The user is redirected to my website and presented with a Login form if it's not logged in yet, otherwise(or after successful authentification) the points will be assigned.

My challenge is to figure out what is the best way to make the data sent(I will guide the sender/third-party app how to do it) to my website secure enough so no one can fake the points transfer. Especially, one of the parameters would be the amount of points, and I think if someone understands how a POST request is looking like he just can fake this parameter.

I was looking into OAuth2 [Client credentials grant](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/client-credentials-grant/) but I'm not sure OAuth2 fits into what I want to achieve, or maybe it is?
The thing is that OAuth2 would add one more step in my flow:

- Third-party (Request access token) -->
- Main App    (Login and release token) -->
- Third-party (Receiving access token) --->
- Main App    (POST request by validating the token) **but still, all the parameters can be faked right?**

So, what would be the best way to make some secure POST requests from third-party Apps?

Comment: Well a way would be that the first websites does an request to an api on the second page which generates an token for an action, the user then gets send to the page xy.php?toke=xyz and if he is logged in the action in teh database will be executed. With this way there is no User input to sanitize

Comment: By "Third-party" you mean you have no control over the other server? `best to make the data sent to my website secure enough`. If you can't control how it's sent then you cant control how secure it is (to some degree).

Comment: If the POST is sent from the third party sever such as via CURL the client can't see it, if it's sent using JavaScript, such as AJAX they can see it.  Generally speaking.  That is because CURL bypasses the client altogether.  But if it's a "Third Party Server"  how do you strictly enforce that.  That said Mr. Third Party would be pretty stupid to send it via AJAX but then I seen lot of stupider things.  You could use a port other then (HTTP) what is 80 or 443 for ssl.  But that's not trivial and has it's own issues.

Comment: Do your applications are very differents ? It is possible to envisage a shared session, like Redis for example ? This way the web app is already submiting as  the authenticated user

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix when I'll decide how to do it, I'll require Mr. third-party to do it as I need it on the server side. | OK, if CURL is secure by default how do I make sure the request came from an authorized one?

Comment: You can tell where the the request came from, IP wise.  You could register client keys with their Severs (outbound) IP address.  It's not impossible to fake an IP, but it's probably beyond your average user.

Comment: @Mcsky it can be any sort of application, and the indegration process should be more or less as easy as possible.

Comment: Oauth2 seem to be the good choice, you keep the related user data in one space 
 and it ensure the authentication. You'll have to setup an oauth2 server for that

Comment: "OK, if CURL is secure by default how do I make sure the request came from an authorized one?" [You can't](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem). You can use public-key cryptography from server to server as a mitigation, but in a public network, you can't guarantee that the client-side software is the one you want it to be.